# Set selected radio from radio group with a value

Tags: jquery

Why am I struggling with this?

I have a value: 5

How do I check the radio button of group "mygroup" with the value of 5?

```
$("input[name=mygroup]").val(5); // doesn't work?
```

Answer (score 411, accepted):

With the help of the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) you can select the input element with the corresponding value. Then you have to set the attribute explicitly, using [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var value = 5;
$("input[name=mygroup][value=" + value + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Since jQuery 1.6, you can also use the [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method with a boolean value (this should be the preferred method):

```
$("input[name=mygroup][value=" + value + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Remember you first need to remove checked attribute from any of radio buttons under one radio buttons group only then you will be able to add checked property / attribute to one of the radio button in that radio buttons group.

Code To Remove Checked Attribute from all radio buttons of one radio button group -

```
$('[name="radioSelectionName"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: .prop('checked', true) is probably better or .is()

Comment: @bladefist: `.is` wouldn't help here, but I agree with `.prop`. It wasn't available back then ;) Will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If the value of the radio button has a decimal, you need to put the value in quotes

Comment: @Robert: Yep, probably. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): *"Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string."*

Comment: Isn't constructing a jquery selector programmatically like this prone to injection attacks? Is there a way to do it without needing to do this?

Comment: See Jonathan's answer.  The jQuery docs show that `.val()` supports setting values on radio or checkbox groups.  This answer's way technically works, but is roundabout and much less readable/memorable.

Comment: prop() method is fine, but attr() method only works once, if you run it again for a different value the checked attr will appear twice and the first presents will be selected, attr() should not be used is this case.

Comment: it should be $("input[name=registration][value=' + value + ']").prop('checked', true); instead of $("input[name='registration'][value=" + value + "]")

Comment: Removing all existing checked attributes first was the bit I was looking for/needed confirmation for.

Comment: To unselect all: $("input[name=mygroup]").prop('checked', false); --- removeAttr('checked') doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 178):

There is a better way of checking radios and checkbox; you have to pass an **array of values** to the val method instead of a raw value

**Note:** If you simply pass the value by itself (without being **inside an array**), that will result in all values of "mygroup" being set to the value.

```
$("input[name=mygroup]").val([5]);
```

Here is the jQuery doc that explains how it works: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value

And `.val([...])` also works with form elements like `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">`, and `<option>`s inside of a `<select>`.

> The inputs and the options having a value that matches one of the elements of the **array** will be checked or selected, while those having a value that don't match one of the elements of the array will be unchecked or unselected

Fiddle demonstrating this working: https://jsfiddle.net/92nekvp3/

Comment: Accepted answer (well, should be).  As of jQuery 1.0, see last example from docs (scroll to bottom): http://api.jquery.com/val/
Copied here: http://jsfiddle.net/JoePC/w1f9ykso/

Comment: This is a nice and consistent way to set all input values. Too bad it's taken me 6 years to learn about it.

Comment: Spent quite a while trying to figure out why all my values in the group were getting set to the passed value instead of checking the value. Turns out I passed the value by itself, not inside an array.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="mygroup"][value="5"]').attr('checked',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JBvSg/).

Comment: @Hunter, thanks...today is clearly **not** my day for jQuery... =/

Answer (score 10):

When you change attribute value like mentioned above the `change` event is not triggered so if needed for some reasons you can trigger it like so

```
$('input[name=video_radio][value="' + r.data.video_radio + '"]')
       .prop('checked', true)
       .trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$("input[name='mygroup'][value='5']").attr("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Pure JavaScript version:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="myradio"][value="5"]').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

`$("input[name='RadioTest'][value='2']").prop('checked', true);`

[JS fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/karanshukla1/qpfLwvyu/3/)

Answer (score 5):

I got an error when using

```
$("input[name=mygroup][value="value"]").prop('checked', true);
```

Working way is

```
$("input[name=mygroup][value='value']").prop('checked', true);
```

The issue is handling quotes(') and double quotes(").

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just write value attribute to it:

```
$(':radio[value=<yourvalue>]').attr('checked',true);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = "Name_radio";
var val = "value_radio";
var rdo = $('*[name="' + key + '"]');
if (rdo.attr('type') == "radio") {
 $.each(rdo, function (keyT, valT){
   if ((valT.value == $.trim(val)) && ($.trim(val) != '') && ($.trim(val) != null))

   {
     $('*[name="' + key + '"][value="' + (val) + '"]').prop('checked', true);
   }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your code does in your answer? At least a sentence or so. And how it solves the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First way assumes there is already a saved reference for the radio group (inputs): `group` and it is wished to select one in the group, by `value`

```js
const group = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="contact"]');

function selectGroupByValue(group, value){
  const input = [...group].find(el => el.value === value);
  if(input) input.checked = true;
}

selectGroupByValue(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="contact"]'), 'phone');
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="mail">
```

This can be taken a step further, to create a more robust function which can change the value of a any group, by its `name`:

```js
function selectGroupByValue(name, value){
  const group = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]`);
  const input = [...group].find(el => el.value === value);
  if(input) input.checked = true;
}

selectGroupByValue('contact', 'phone');
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="mail">
```

The below example is completely different as it does not have a cached reference to the radio group, but does a lookup every time:

```js
const selectedValue = 'phone';
const input = document.querySelector(`input[name="contact"][value="${selectedValue}"`);
if(input) input.checked = true;
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="mail">
```

If the group is within a `<form>` element:
*(intentionally did not break the `for` iterator)*

```js
for (const [index, input] of document.forms[0].contact.entries())
  if(input.value === `phone`)
    input.checked = true
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">
  <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">
  <input type="radio" name="contact" value="mail">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name="mygroup"]').val([5])
```

Comment: Can you explain what makes your solution different from the other solutions already provided?

Comment: @Giovani Vercauteren , we should give the name as a string. So I give the mygroup as a string in the code.