# Select radio button from external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you select a radio button using external link such as **/page.html#item1** or **/page.html?item1** so that when the page loads it's already selected

```
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-1">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-2">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-3">
```

Any method will do, javascript or jquery

Comment: Firstly your `input` elements *need* to have a `value` attribute. Secondly, this is quite easy if you take the time to research. Break it down in to steps. [How do I get hash from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) [How can I get querystring values from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) [How can I set selected radio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618733/set-selected-radio-from-radio-group-with-a-value)

Comment: Value isn't important to explain what I'm looking for or for the function to work. Javascript isn't a language I know. I was hoping someone can show a working example.

Comment: There is a difference between "I am having an issue with a specific problem." and "Can someone do it for me?".  The first is what we are looking for from S.O. questions.

Comment: This forum is full help with "how to" examples. Thanks for the vote down and a self-righteous attitude. Someone else got the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to check radio button on window load.

Consider your url to be of form - 
**scheme://example.com/myproject/abc.php?id=2**

After running below code snippet you will encounter an error so try it on your site it requires url inorder to work.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  let prepend = 'item-';
  let elem = 'input[type=radio]';
  let url = window.location.href;
  let keyVal = '1';

  if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1)
    keyVal = url.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];

  let id = prepend + keyVal;

  $(elem).each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).prop('id') === id)
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-1">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-2">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-3">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-4">
<input type="radio" name="price" id="item-5">
```

Hope, this works for you..!! :) :)

Comment: It works! You're awesome. Thanks.

Comment: How can I make the first radio box be selected by default if no id is entered in url such as example.com/myproject/abc.php  I've been messing around with the code but no luck

Comment: Thank u @mr.data1. Please check above edited code snippet.

Comment: That did it. Thanks again! You've been very helpful :)