# Change radio button using select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a post showing how to change the clicked radio button but I was wondering how to change the radio button based on a select dropdown. Specifically when the select value = "yes" change the selected radio button to yes.

```html
<select id='yes_no'>
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="yes" /> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="no" checked /> No
</form>
```

I've tried using answers like from [Set selected radio from radio group with a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618733/set-selected-radio-from-radio-group-with-a-value) but this still does not work.

```
$('#yes_no').change(function(){
   $("input[name='category'][value=" + $(this).val()  + "]").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Any leads?

Comment: The jquery code you provided seems to work fine? Why do you think it "does not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page load the change event does not fire (automatically). Since the radio with `value="no"` has the attribute `checked`, by default that is set to checked.

To get the correct value set on page load you can either set the `checked` attribute to `value="yes"` radio (and remove `checked` from `value="no"` radio)

**OR:** Trigger the event (*change*) like the following way:

```js
$('#yes_no').change(function(){
   $("input[name='category'][value=" + $(this).val()  + "]").prop('checked', true);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='yes_no'>
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="yes" /> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="no" checked /> No
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You could set initial checked value as `Yes` .

Actually its working. At the time of changing select. `No` value radio already checked.so its not reflected with in UI

```js
$('#yes_no').change(function() {
  $("input[name='category'][value="+$(this).val()+"]").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='yes_no'>
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="yes" checked/> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="no" /> No
</form>
```