# Selecting radio button

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Here is jquery script used to select radio button.

```
function radio(){
       var presetValue = "scholar";
$("[name=identity]").filter("[value="+presetValue+"]").attr("checked","checked");
}
```

The scrip is invoked on page load.
This is XHTML peace of code:

```
<label for="scholar"> Scholar </label>
        <input type="radio" name="identity" id="scholar" value="scholar"  />
        </td>

        <td>
        <label for="oracle"> Oracle </label>
        <input type="radio" name="identity" id="oracle" value="oracle"/>
        </td>

        <td>
        <label for="both"> Both </label>
        <input type="radio" name="identity" id="both" value="both"/>
```

When the program runs that 'scholar' radio button is not selected.
What might be the problem?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery >= 1.6, you *should* use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Also, you're using a complicated selector for nothing. Since your inputs have id's, this will do it:

```
$('#scholar').prop('checked', true);
```

If `presetValue` changes (i.e: you simplified the code), do this:

```
$('#' + presetValue).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [how to set radio option checked onload with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871063/how-to-set-radio-option-checked-onload-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
function radio(){
       var presetValue = "scholar";
$("input[value="+presetValue+"]").attr("checked",true);
}
```