# JQuery OnDocumentLoad Check Radio Item

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a specific radio buttom item to be checked using JQuery when the page loads.

Can this be done with jquery?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871063/how-to-set-radio-option-checked-onload-with-jquery

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function () {    
  $("#myRadioId").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is so easily googled, the best way to learn is to try it your self. We only get better by working things out.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/ 
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#your id").prop("checked", true);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourRadioButtonId").attr("checked", "checked");
//Or
  $("#yourRadioButtonId").prop("checked",true);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('radio-selector[name="the-value-to-set"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```