# Using jquery, set the value of a radio button

Tags: jquery, html

I have some straight HTML code

```
<input type="radio" name="GRSReboot" value="1" checked >On</input>
<input type="radio" name="GRSReboot" value="2" >Off</input>
```

I need to set the checked value of the field using jquery.

I do not want to use the runat=server options,
so i need to know, how do i tell JQuery to set the value of the radio button group?

thank you

Edit -  The controls are a radio button group, and i need to set one of the controls as checked based on a value returned from the server.
thank you

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525128/jquery-set-radio-button

Comment: Please read the question as well as the title before marking this as a duplicate!

Comment: What version of jQuery and what do you want to set? The `value` or `checked`?

Comment: Was any answer helpful? or the problem is still there?

Comment: The answer provided by @JonnySooter below worked for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844651/1735836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eun2B/)**

It's a bit unclear for me if you want to check/uncheck or give it a value.

If you want to give it or change it's value, you can use this:

```
$("input[name=GRSReboot]").prop('value','200');
```

If you want to change the value of the checked one you can use:

```
$("input[name=GRSReboot]:checked").prop('value','200');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  :-)