# check radio button whe parent div is selected?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a radio button that I would be like to be selectable if the user clicks the div thats its inside of. I have a click event for the div but I can't seem to get the radio button to check.

heres my code:

```
var new_div = document.createElement('div');
        new_div.setAttribute('id', 'controlDiv');
        new_div.setAttribute('class', 'ansClass');
var newAnswer = document.createElement('input');
        newAnswer.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        newAnswer.setAttribute('name', 'choice');
        newAnswer.setAttribute('class', 'radioButton');
        $(newAnswer).attr("id", "button"+j);


        var newLabel = $("<label>", {id: "label"+j, class: "ansLabel", text: "answer"+j});


        $(new_div).append(newAnswer); 
        $(new_div).append(newLabel);



$( "#controlDiv" ).click(function() {
    var radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
    radButton.click();
      //  $(radButton).attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525128/jquery-set-radio-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$( "#controlDiv" ).click(function() {
    var radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
    $(radButton).prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: thanks! Worked like a charm. Why would prop be better than attr?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a similar answer to Arun's, except modified a little to allow for unchecking as well:

```
$('#controlDiv').click( function(){
  var radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
  if(radButton).is(':checked')){
    $(radButton).removeAttr('checked');
  } else {
    $(radButton).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

I would maybe go a step further and provide the radio button with a specific ID. If it's one of many, try to go with a class. This just gives you more specificity in your coding.

Comment: Thanks this would work, but a have my buttons in groups of 4 so they deselect automatically when another is pressed.